# Can anybody help me find a cable housing ferrule that looks like this?

Tags: cable-housing

I've spent many hours looking for this and can't find them anywhere. I need them to repair a special fitting.

[image]

Comment: What is the special fitting?

Comment: I'm guessing its a brake cable, and goes at the entrance to the lever?  As such it looks like something custom to your levers.  Can you give us more information about how its used?